# Passing the primitive type and calling methods via reflection

Tags: java

I am working on a kind of Framework. Here I will have to call a particular method on a particular class with particular parameters. I will receive parameter values in string form.

like inputs will be,

---

class name : com.classes.MyClass

method name : setPrimtiveType

Value : "true"

type of value : boolean

---

Here the problem is that the method I am trying to call via reflection accepts primitive type.
this type is also an input to set the particular parameter.

I am not getting any in reflection so this can be achieved.

Comment: You're being unclear. Show some code or explain yourself more clearly.

Comment: there is `boolean.class` - if that's what you are asking

Comment: You may want to map primitive types of value to object wrappers, if this is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

if this is your class

```
class MyClass {
    public static void setPrimitiveType(boolean v) {
    }
}
```

then this is how to set boolean value

```
MyClass.class.getMethod("setPrimitiveType", boolean.class).invoke(null, true);
```

Comment: PS: If the method has 2 parameters ... setPrimitiveType(String status, boolean v) ... following has to be done: MyClass.class.getMethod("setPrimitiveType", new Class[] {String.class, boolean.class}).invoke(null, new Object[] {status, Boolean.valueOf(v)});